# Rails nested parameter parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

I've got a model `Klass`, which can have several `Note` objects. In my form I have the field name as `klass[notes][][note_ids][]`.

Now, if I pass the following parameters into the request:

```
klass[notes][][note_ids][]=5cb95789-6c35-4d39-aa17-c3ddbbbcf540&klass[notes][][note_ids][]=2cfb26df-21b4-43d7-aa65-735569d42ad9
```

They get parsed as follows (using Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query):

```
{"klass"=>{"notes"=>[{"note_ids"=>["5cb95789-6c35-4d39-aa17-c3ddbbbcf540", "2cfb26df-21b4-43d7-aa65-735569d42ad9"]}]}}
```

How do I make it so that they instead get parsed into the following:

```
{"klass"=>{"notes"=>[{"note_ids"=>["5cb95789-6c35-4d39-aa17-c3ddbbbcf540"]}, {"note_ids"=>["2cfb26df-21b4-43d7-aa65-735569d42ad9"]}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current scheme, it will be impossible for the parser to tell if the two ids are to be grouped at the `note_ids` level or at the `notes` level. It groups them at the first valid level it finds.

You could help the parser by grouping the outer level manually. For example,

```
klass[notes][0][note_ids][]=1&klass[notes][1][note_ids][]=2
```

gets parsed as

```
 {"klass"=>{"notes"=>{"0"=>{"note_ids"=>["1"]}, "1"=>{"note_ids"=>["2"]}}}}
```